# Choosing LC oscillator components

Tags: capacitor, inductor, oscillator

I understand that the frequency of a simple LC oscillator can be selected by using

$$f=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

Say that I am trying to get an oscillator to operate at some arbitrary frequency of 60 Hz.  I could simply select values of \$L=.0027\$ and \$C=.0027\$.  That would be a capacitor of \$2.7mF\$ and an inductor of \$2.7mH\$.

But there are an infinite number of solutions.  My capacitor could be arbitrarily large, say \$500mF\$, which would require a \$14\mu H\$ inductor.  Or the other way around: a \$500mH\$ inductor and a \$14\mu F\$ capacitor.

What are some criteria that I should use to select these?  Is there a reason to keep the values similar in magnitude?  Are certain values of capacitor or inductors prohibitively expensive?  How do the choices I make in value affect the operation of the circuit?

Assume that I will be producing an output in the audio range, \$20Hz-20kHz\$

Comment: [Here's a 500mH inductor.](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/410/C_36X-1892607.pdf) It weighs half a pound - over 200 grams.  It costs 10 Euros.

Comment: Ok so that's definitely a consideration!

Comment: @nuggethead Are you aware that there are many RC-oscillator types (without inductor)?

Comment: @LvW nope was not aware of that.  I'm a newbie.  Enlighten me

Comment: @nuggethead One versatile and simple oscillator circuit was mentioned here already (answer from Andy aka): WIEN BRIDGE OSCILLATOR.  My recommendation: Start a google search for "RC oscillator".

Comment: Why *arbitrary frequency of 60 Hz*?  To get that, you need big cap and/or big inductor.  That is not arbitrary, that is hard.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat arbitrary because I made it up on the spot.  I want to learn more about how things work.  Audio spectrum is most interesting to me because I lack the equipment to make much progress on a breadboard with RF.  So, 60 it is.

Comment: But the math is what it is because the frequency is so small and meaningless to audio signals. It is not arbitrary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To resolve this apparently unsolvable problem you have to consider the Q-factor of the tuned circuit. In an ideal scenario, Q is infinite but, in the real world, Q is limited by inductor series resistance losses and capacitor dielectric losses. At 60 Hz it's going to be dominated by inductor series resistance losses.

So, if your inductance has 1 Ω series resistance and is 2.7 mH, then the Q of the 60 Hz LC tank would be unity (1). On the other hand, if you went for a 27 mH inductor, with a 270 μF capacitor, the Q would be 10 (for 1 Ω series resistance in the coil).

It boils down to how much Q factor you need to make your LC oscillator. Higher is usually better. For a parallel tuned circuit the formula for Q is this: -

$$Q = \dfrac{1}{R_{INDUCTOR}}\sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}$$

And, as you can see, the higher the inductance, the higher the Q factor will be.

> *Are certain values of capacitor or inductors prohibitively expensive?*

Inductors at this frequency (60 Hz) are usually about ten times the cost of the resonating capacitor (rough guide).

> *Say that I am trying to get an oscillator to operate at some arbitrary
> frequency of 60 Hz.*

I wouldn't use an LC oscillator for this frequency; I'd consider using a Wien bridge oscillator with amplitude control or, maybe an astable oscillator with a multi-order filter on the output to convert the square wave to a decent sine wave. Either of these options would be better and cheaper than an LC oscillator. A relaxation oscillator plus output filter would probably be best. [Relaxation oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_oscillator): -

[image]

Comment: Q-factor is new to me.  Where can I learn more about it?

Comment: Q-factor is the ratio of inductive reactance to series resistance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor

Comment: this formula implies it's better to add some artificial resistance (as much as possible - gigaohms) to improve Q. Is that right? I can't believe that.

Comment: Oops I got the resistance shown incorrectly... Fixed now @user253751

Comment: The quality factor Q is a measure for the quality of the parts (quality is reduced due to resistive losses). This applies mainly to the inductor. Considering an LC resonant circuit, the Q-factor determines the sharpness of the resonant curve - and with it the bandwidth. The Q-factor is the ratio of the center frequency to the 3-dB bandwidth.

Comment: @nuggethead if you have no more questions then please read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

What you need to consider is the impedance of the circuit, which is given by \$\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$.

Your choice of 2.7 mF / 2.7 mH would give you 1 ohm impedance. 500 mH and 14 uF would give you 190 ohms.

If you are building an oscillator around a low powered FET amplifier, you would want to choose a high impedance. A lower impedance would be appropriate for a low impedance bipolar amplifier.

It also gives you an idea of the Q of the tuned circuit when paired with your amplifier impedances.

Comment: Where does the impedance formula come from?  Could it be derived from something familiar to a newbie?

Comment: @nuggethead: the formula is derived from the characteristic polynomial of the 2nd order transfer function, \$s^{2}+(\omega_{N}/Q)s+\omega^{2}_{N}\$.